# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Model'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

There are lots of exemples about my problem but I was not be able to find my problem here. I read most of then and I saw the problem is related to Bind Json to Model.

**I have the following Json string: [EDITED]**

```
{
 answered: 88983,
 total: 88983,
 tma: "74.0",
 tme: "7.0",
 total_condos: 71,
 byday: {
 answerbyday: [
 {
  day: "2018-2-1",
  total: 3242,
  tme: "5.0",
  tma: "75.0"
 },
 {
  day: "2018-2-2",
  total: 3814,
  tme: "8.0",
  tma: "74.0"
 },
 {
  day: "2018-2-3",
  total: 3157,
  tme: "5.0",
  tma: "67.0"
 }
]
},
condos: [
{
 condo: "2000",
 name: "2000 - PORTER CUIABA",
 total: 1155,
 answered: 1155,
 tma: "50.0",
 tme: "7.0"
},
{
 condo: "5010",
 name: "5010 - COND PASSAREDO",
 total: 1347,
 answered: 1347,
 tma: "80.0",
 tme: "7.0"
},
{
 condo: "5020",
 name: "5020 - COND OURO PRETO",
 total: 241,
 answered: 241,
 tma: "61.0",
 tme: "7.0"
}
]
}
```

JSON RESUMED

```
{
answered: 88983,
total: 88983,
tma: "74.0",
tme: "7.0",
total_condos: 71,
byday: {
answerbyday: []
},
condos: []
}
```

My Model is like Below:

```
public class GroupbyDay
{
    public int answered { get; set; }        
    public int total { get; set; }
    public double tma { get; set; }
    public double tme { get; set; }
    public int total_condos { get; set; }
    public byday byday { get; set; }
    public List<condos> condos { get; set; }
}

public class byday
{
    public List<answerbyday> answerbyday { get; set; }   
}

public class answerbyday
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public double tme { get; set; }
    public double tma { get; set; }
}

public class condos
{
    public string condo { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int answered { get; set; }
    public double tme { get; set; }
    public double tma { get; set; }
}
```

On My controller im calling the method:

```
string URL1 = "http://" + server + "/report/calls/synthetic/agents?from=" + data1 + "&to=" + data2 + "&groupby=day";
var webRequest1 = WebRequest.Create(URL1);

if (webRequest1 != null)
{
   webRequest1.Method = "GET";
   webRequest1.Timeout = 300000;
   webRequest1.ContentType = "application/json";

   using (var s = webRequest1.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
   {
       using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
       {
          var lista = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GroupbyDay>(sr.ReadToEnd());
          return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

What Im missing here? I have already reviewed all code and couldnt find what Im doing wrong.

EDITED: I SENT MY JSON WRONG.

Comment: well, your"byday" property opens as an object and closes as an array. not sure if thats a typo, but check there first

Comment: Ignoring the Typo on the first { for byday, the JSON appears to have that as an array, but in you model declaration you have a type of byday, that has a property of answerbyday which is a collection. This doesn't match the JSON (i.e. collection within object) that has just a collection (Array)

Comment: To bind to your model it would need to be `byday: { answerbyday: [ { day: "2018-2-1", ... }, { day: "2018-2-2", ... } ] }`

Comment: Sorry I sent wrong JSON first time, I edited to correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your JSON through online convertor [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/), I get..

```
public class Answerbyday
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string tme { get; set; }
    public string tma { get; set; }
}

public class Byday
{
    public List<Answerbyday> answerbyday { get; set; }
}

public class Condo
{
    public string condo { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int answered { get; set; }
    public string tma { get; set; }
    public string tme { get; set; }
}

public class GroupbyDay // RootObject
{
    public int answered { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string tma { get; set; }
    public string tme { get; set; }
    public int total_condos { get; set; }
    public Byday byday { get; set; }
    public List<Condo> condos { get; set; }
}
```

Take a look at Microsoft's article [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization), and from Newtonsoft: [Serialization Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

Comment: Hey Adam, my problem is about the object order?

Comment: @RogerioAzevedo actually, with serialization, you need to get the dependency (as you say "object order") correct.  As well, it's case sensitive stuff here, which is why you will want to review what data annotations means to serialization.  Answer updated with good article about serialization..

Comment: I tried changing my model, but got same error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Sistema.Model.GroupbyDay' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Please update your answer with latest model.  And also update your posted JSON.  The part about "JSON RESUMED" does not make sense.  Have you pasted your JSON into http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I used json2csharp.com and made the changes. Works fine now Thank you!